# Don't set charset in header

Tags: php, apache, header

How can I avoid, that PHP (or apache) automatically adds a **charset=utf-8** to the Content-type eader when sending the content type?

(Reason is that this is causing issues with Internet Explorer)

```
orange public$ cat test.php 
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/xml');
orange public$ curl -v example.com.orange.me.local/test.php
#*   Trying 10.0.0.1...
* Connected to example.com.orange.me.local (10.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /test.php HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com.orange.imi.local
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 01 Jun 2016 16:24:49 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
< Content-Length: 0
< Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
< 
* Connection #0 to host example.com.orange.me.local left intact
```

Comment: probably that is better to see what kind of *issues with Internet Explorer* because utf-8 is the better way in 99% of cases.

Comment: It is a proxy-kind of app - so I just want to send the header as I get it. While you are basically right, I think it is a valid approach in this case.

Comment: it does not matter if proxy or not. I can't see good reason so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to remove the charset using

```
ini_set('default_charset', '');
```

in my script and

```
AddDefaultCharset off
```

in my .htaccess